# Delphi Indy TIdHTTP.Get() high CPU load

Tags: http, delphi, indy

I saw a similar question here, but no useful answer, so let me please write it again.

My application is using too much CPU, for a test example I pick a slow site (https://www.hao123.com/) from top10 slowest sites, and read it with 100 threads simultaneously.

There is no response processing; one request is taking about 5 seconds, so it looks logical for me that my threads should use about 0% CPU being almost all the time waiting for a response.

```
procedure mth.Execute;
var
  tm1: dword;
begin
  HTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create;
  HTTP.ConnectTimeout:=60000;
  HTTP.ReadTimeout:=60000;
  ssl:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  HTTP.IOHandler:=ssl;
  HTTP.HandleRedirects:=true;
  HTTP.ProtocolVersion:=pv1_1;

  repeat
    sleep(5);
    If StartWork then begin
      tm1:=TimeGetTime;
      s:=HTTP.Get('https://www.hao123.com/');
      GlobalTiming:=(GlobalTiming * 9 + (TimeGetTime-tm1)) / 10;
    end;
  until Terminated;
  HTTP.Free;
  ssl.Free;
end;
```

The test application starts creating threads with `StartWork=false`. As long as I dont set `StartWork:=true`, CPU load is about 0%

[image]

**UPDATE:** to answer comments below: 100 threads running `sleep(5)` cycle DO NOT load CPU

As soon as I start readers by setting `StartWork:=true`, I see 10% CPU load on my 16-core Ryzen. When running on a 1-core VDS, this turns into a really painful problem.

The question is: how is a simple operation which should just wait, actually using that much CPU?  How to "optimize" it?

[image]

**UPDATE2:**

Hard to explain that the issue has nothing to do with the `sleep(5)` so 2 more pictures:

I've replaced `sleep(5)` with `sleep(100 + random(100))`

[image]

The picture from 2-cores vds:

[image]

Comment: `sleep(5)` is a very short time to sleep. And you have 100 threads polling 100 sites at the same time in rapid succession.  So it is no wonder your CPU load is high.  Use a larger sleep interval, and even consider randomizing the interval a little bit so all 100 threads are not operating at EXACTLY the same time.

Comment: Or consider using a thread pool with task objects instead. Each site poll is a task.  Create a queue of tasks. When a thread is available, grab a task from the queue, perform the task, grab the next task from the queue, and so on. Run only as many threads as you have cores (or a small multiply of the number of cores). When a task is finished, queue a new task to run if `StartWork` is still true.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there is no problems with threads themself, As long as I dont set StartWorK to true, all 100 threads are running `sleep(5)` empty cycle without loading CPU

Comment: @Ken I guess it won't be 200 times a second because of the 30ms clock granularity. The only thing here that could add up us the large cost of kernel transition when calling sleep.

Comment: @KenWhite please read carefully , I added 1 more picture to illustrate the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the GET request takes about 5 seconds, so `sleep` is called once in 5 seconds, not 200 times in a second

Comment: @michael Ken was describing the StartWork being False scenario. My response was to that.

Comment: On https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe their is ALStressHTTPServer app (https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALStressHTTPServer/win32/ALStressHTTPServer.exe) that can run 100 simultaneaous thread doing http query. it's take around max 20% of my cpu (i guess mostly to update the grid), but i use winHttp api and not Indy ... can you try to see if that change you CPU usage ?

Comment: David Heffernan >>The only thing here that could add up us the large cost of kernel transition when calling sleep.
You are confused with Thread Suspending. Normal sleep is very easy operation, - Wait functions are using it.

Comment: I think that you have a wrong assumption about CPU usage. Its normal that multithreaded application with a lot of work with strings and encryption can take a lot of CPU usage. Especially, if we talk about one-core CPU. In my tests with 100 threads and this site, I have got 15% of cpu usage (2 cores, 3GHz). And site is not very slow - on my side it takes around 500 ms to get response.

Comment: @zed I can admit (but still dont understand what kind of work is actually done by just reading of a response with **no processing **) that 500ms delayed reads may load CPU but in my test it was 5 000 ms (2 days ago. i used google "top 10 slowest sites" to find that one)

Comment: @zed I will think about Further testing idea, for now it looks like CPU usage somehow related to site's response time.. atleast there is a logic in test results: your machine is using 10x less CPU having the site 10x faster

Comment: By the way, what Indy version did you use? I tested on Delphi 10.2.3 with builtin Indy 10.6.2.5366 (from IdVers.inc), target platform: 32-bit.